# how to use vector of objects in different files

Tags: c++, vector, static, extern, modular-design

how can i access a static vector variable in main file which is declared in header file and populated in source file.Actual code is little bit big so below is an example what i have tried.

**class.h**

```
class a{

    private:
      int x;

    public:
      friend void createVec();
};

void createVec();
static std::vector<a> vec;
```

**source.cpp**

```
include"class.h"

extern std::vector<a> vec; //if i remove this line code runs and don't show any error 
                           // -of undefined variable
void createVec()
{
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
  {
    vec.push_back(i); //while debugging and watching vec, code is able to populate vec
                      //but i doubt whether is it vector declared in class.h or not
  }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

extern std::vector<a> vec;
int main()
{
  createVec();
  cout<<vec.size() //it prints 0 instead of 10  
}
```

Comment: Just like you would use an instance of any other type in many files. `std::vector` is not magic in this respect.

Comment: @juanchopanza but the main file is not accessing `vec`

Comment: The point is that `std::vector` is not different from `int` or any other type in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're declaring `vec` to be `static`. In this context (a global/static variable), this means the variable should exist only in the translation unit (.cpp file) where the declaration is found.

Since you've put this inside the .h file and `#include`d this in several source files, the two .cpp files will both have their own `static std::vector<a> vec`, rather than sharing the same one. Hence, pushing back in one file does not affect the vector in the other.

The solution here is to remove `static` from the declaration of `vec` and move it into one of the `cpp` files.

To clarify: putting the declaration of a variable in **global scope** automatically gives it **static storage duration**, which means its lifetime ends after `main` returns. Using `extern` means you specify that the variable has been declared in another .cpp file. Declaring a global variable `static` only means it will not be available in other .cpp files. Hence, if you want to use a global variable in multiple .cpp files, it should be delared in one, without static, and you should declare it as `extern` in all other .cpp files where it is used.

Comment: thanks for answer and  explaining the concept `the two .cpp files will both have their own static std::vector<a> vec`.As you have explained there is no need to use `static` so does declaring a variable `extern` makes it available through out the life of program?

Comment: @Rahul Indeed, you do not need to use `static`. But you need to have it declared (without `static` and without `extern`) in one of the .cpp files. Declaring it as `extern` in the other .cpp files allows you to use it in that file, by saying that it exists but is declared in another .cpp file.

Comment: @Rahul All variables which are global (not declared in a function or class) have static storage duration, which means that they are available throughout the duration of the program (more specifically, until you reach the end of `main`).

Answer (score 0):

in class.h:

```
extern std::vector<a> vec;
```

in source.cpp:

```
std::vector<a> vec;
```

in main.cpp: remove the declaration, including class.h in enough

Answer (score 0):

I would argue against sharing vectors over translation units, because I believe in avoiding global instances when possible.

You can do that by putting the vector in a class, together with the `populateVector()` and `printVector()` functions, and then instantiate that class in main and call the functions.